# Infinite counter with increment at two decimals

Tags: jquery, counter

Trying to create an infinite counter that starts at 10.41 and increases by 10.41 every second. Have looked at various tutorials but I cannot find one that will account for the increase with a decimal number unit (10.41) every second. This is the code I am using:

```js
setTimeout(start, 0);

var i = 100;
var num = document.getElementById('number');

function start() {
  setInterval(increase, 100);
}

function increase() {
    if (i < 100000) {
      i++;
      num.innerText = i;
    }
}
```

Comment: so add 10.41 to the number....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, all you need to do is, instead of `i++` you need to use `i += 10.41`. I have also changed the initial `i` value to zero because you want it to start from `10.41` and timer to `1000` instead of `100`:

```js
setTimeout(start, 0);

var i = 0;
var num = document.getElementById('number');

function start() {
  increase();
  setInterval(increase, 1000);
}

function increase() {
  if (i < 100000) {
    i += 10.41;
    num.innerText = i.toFixed(2);
  }
}
```

```html
<span id="number"></span>
```

Also, I truncated it off to two decimal places using `i.toFixed(2);`.

Comment: I would `num.textContent = i.toFixed(2);` instead, though.

Comment: I see...thank you for your help....is there a way to increase the counter by 10.41 without showing decimals but counting them anyway?

Comment: @Cherubrock74 Yes, there's `.toFixed(2)`, make it `.toFixed(0)`.

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman not sure if I should start another thread about this but is there a way to keep the counter counting even if a user browse different web pages on the same website? Sort of a session counter? Please advise thank you

Comment: @Cherubrock74 It's not possible with JavaScript because ... Or yes, as you said, you can do a session counter. Wanna ask another question? Happy to answer that!  Instead of using a local variable, use a session storage variable. But keep in mind, you can have this only in browsers that support localStorage API.

Comment: @Cherubrock74 Wanna create a new question or have you got your answer?

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman I added a new question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64775260/perpetual-counter-within-the-same-web-session

Comment: @Cherubrock74 I'll check.

Answer (score 1):

I would do like:

```js
function Incro(increment, interval, execFunc){
  let iv;
  this.increment = increment; this.interval = interval; this.execFunc = execFunc; this.sum = 0;
  this.start = ()=>{
    iv = setInterval(()=>{
      this.sum += this.increment; this.execFunc();
    }, this.interval);
    return this;
  }
  this.stop = ()=>{
    clearInterval(iv); iv = undefined;
  }
}
const incro = new Incro(10.41, 1000, function(){
  console.clear(); console.log(this.sum.toFixed(2));
  if(this.sum > 100)this.stop();
});
console.log('0.00');
incro.start();
setTimeout(()=>{
  incro.stop();
  setTimeout(()=>{
    incro.start();
  }, 2000);
}, 5150);
```

As you can see JavaScript time is not exact.

Comment: Thank you...what do you mean that java script time is not exact?